# Reading file with colon separators in c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I need to read from file and print line by line

Here is my file with colon separators

```
Miami:Sunny:USA
London:Rainy:England
```

and print as it's below:

```
City: Miami Weather:Sunny Country: USA
City: London Weather:Rainy Country: England
```

However I got this:

```
City:  Miami Weather:  Sun Country USA
London City:  Rain Weather:  England Country USA
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void read_from_file()
{
    string city;
    string c;
    string w;
    fstream file("list.txt");
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while (file.good())
        {
            getline(file, city, ':');
            cout << " City:  " << name;
            getline(file, w, ':');
            cout << " Weather:  " << w;
            getline(file, c, ':');
            cout << " Country: " << c;
        }
        file.close();
    }
}

int main()
{
    read_from_file();
    return 0;
}
```

I think my problem colon in `getline(file, w, ':');` but when I put `'\n'` instead it crashes.

Is there anybody who can help?

Comment: Try moving the first `getline` into the loop condition, IE `while(getline(file, city, ':'))`

Comment: @Namfuak Oh, thanks it helped but it looks like

    `City: Miami Weather: Sunny Country: USA`

    `London Weather: Rainy Country: England`

Answer (score 1):

The newlines in your file happen after the country, so when you read in the country, you should be using a newline delimiter (this is done by default if you leave out the delimiter argument). It looks like you tried doing this when reading into `w` instead of `c`.

Instead of:

`getline(file, c, ':');`

Use:

`getline(file, c);`

Also, when you output, you will need to insert a newline yourself after your print the country.

`cout << " Country: " << c << endl;`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any colons after your country so you shouldn't use it as a delimiter either.

Change

```
getline(file, c, ':');
```

to

```
getline(file, c);
```

so it'll use the default newline as delimiter.

Also your code would just output everything on one line so you might want to change

```
cout<<" Country: "<<c;
```

to

```
cout<<" Country: "<<c << '\n';
```

too.

Might consider reading [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/1942027) too, checking for `EOF` or `file.good()` isn't usually the way to check the input. In your case it doesn't make any problems though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each line is not TERMINATED with a colon (:), but your `getline` is requesting a read upto the next ':', which is on the next line. Change it to use a newline on the LAST column.